# How to get a sign instead of a value in html?

Tags: html, angularjs

In my user table, there is an active field, instead of `true`/`false` I want the checkbox to be highlighted (it does not matter) if `true` and a minus sign (not important) if `false`.

And when changing user data, I want to click on one of these checkboxes to set the value.

How can I give a tick instead of a value?

```
    <!-- user.html -->

    <div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
    <div class="row  table-responsive">
        <table class="simple-little-table">
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Active</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:$scope.query">
                <td>{{ user.id}}</td>
                <td>{{ user.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{ user.lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{ user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{ user.email}}</td>
                <td>{{ user.roles}}</td>
                <td>{{user.active}}</td>
                <td><div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editUser(user.id)">Редактировать</button>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

that's `edituser.html`

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12" style="margin: 15px">
    Активация:
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-10" style="margin: 5px;">
        <textarea style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; height:3rem;  resize: none;" ng-model="user.active"
                  ng-if="editActive"/>
    <div ng-if="!editActive" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; overflow-wrap: break-word">
        {{user.active}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">
    <button ng-click="changeActive()"
            ng-if="editActive">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
           style="size: 20px"/>
    </button>
    <button ng-click="changeActive()"
            ng-if="!editActive">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"
           style="size: 20px"/>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your point,you want to show checkbox and minus sign depend active  field and you also want to check or tick the check box to change the data.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-if="user.active" 
ng-checked="user.active" ng-click="editUser(user.id)">
```

display minus when active false.

```
<span ng-if="!user.active"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"/></span>
```

Comment: earned in the case when it shows the result, but I don’t understand why I don’t accept you in the case when I change user data

Comment: please see my new answer

Comment: I think that I do not convey the value of this check

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12" style="margin: 15px">
    Активация:
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-10" style="margin: 5px;">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-if="editActive"
           ng-checked="user.active" ng-click="editUser(user.id)">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-if="!editActive"
           ng-checked="user.active" ng-click="editUser(user.id)">
    <!--<input type="checkbox" ng-if="user.active"-->
           <!--ng-checked="user.active" ng-click="editUser(user.id)">-->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">
    <button ng-click="changeActive()"
            ng-if="editActive">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
           style="size: 20px"/>
    </button>
    <button ng-click="changeActive()"
            ng-if="!editActive">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"
           style="size: 20px"/>

    </button>
</div>
```

after edit, shows ticks but does not change the value